# Is there a DBMS-indepent way to fill a given column with an incrementing/ascending number?

Tags: sql

Lets say I have a table with a varchar colum and and integer column. The varchar columns are filled and the integer columns are all emtpy:

[image]

I would like to execute a signle SQL update statement which populates the integer column with an ascending number like this:

[image]

This update statement should not be DBMS-specific, it should run on all popular SQL DBMSs. Is there a way to do this?

**I edited the contents of the varchar column as the previous version of my question implied that they were numbered and distinct. They are not - they are completely random.**

Comment: In theory there is, but in reality there isn't. You **will** have to write DBMS specific queries

Comment: If your database supports SQL Window Functions, as it should if it supports recent enough ANSI SQL, then `update mytable set my_integer_column = row_number() over (order by my_varchar_column)` could work.

Comment: @Corion: unfortunately that use of window functions like that is not allowed in the SQL standard if I'm not mistaken. And even it the standard allowed it I don't know of any DBMS that would support it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `subquery` :

```
UPDATE t
     SET my_integer_column = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t t1 WHERE t1.My_Varchar_Column <= t.My_Varchar_Column);
```

Comment: [MySQL error - Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a8a584a79491bccea2e45d1852c45969) You should handle  most popular RDBMSes.

Comment: I had to rephrase my question as it gave you a wrong impression about the contents of the varchar column. Do you also have a solution which works regardless of the contents of the varchar column?

Answer (score 0):

If `My_Varchar_Column` is unique you could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET my_integer_column = 
        (SELECT rn
        FROM  (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY My_Varchar_Column) AS rn
               FROM table_name t) sub
        WHERE table_name.My_Varchar_Column = sub.My_Varchar_Column);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3bf287cb2c27f70b94069dd99aec3dd2)**

It will work on modern RDBMS like PostgreSQL/MySQL 8.0/Maria DB/SQLite 3.25/Oracle/SQL Server.

Comment: I tried it. The error is: `Undefined function 'row_number' in expression.`

Comment: @fukanchik: then you are not using a DBMS supporting [modern SQL](https://modern-sql.com/)

Comment: @fukanchik Are you using MS Access?

Comment: I am sorry, I messed up my question, so that your answer was based on the impression that the contents in the varchar column are unique. They are not, they are completely random. Do you have an idea how to solve that?